# Merge data frame using non-unique probabilistic key

Tags: r, merge

The goal is to merge `df2` into `df1` where the key values in `df2` are not unique but are in groups where each has a probabilistic value.  A simple example:

```
df1
#    key
#1     A
#2     B
#3     C
#4     C
#5     A
#6     A
#7     D

df2
#     key  code prob
#1      A     1 0.75
#2      A     2 0.25
#3      B     1 0.95
#4      B     2 0.05
#5      C     1 0.20
#6      C     2 0.25
#7      C     3 0.55
#8      D     1 0.33
#9      D     2 0.33
#10     D     3 0.33
```

The expected result would be something like the following where `code` has been assigned based upon the probabilities in `df2`:

```
#     key code
#1     A     1
#2     B     1
#3     C     3
#4     C     3
#5     A     2
#6     A     1
#7     D     2
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(key = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), .Names = "key", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

df2 <- structure(list(key = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    code = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), prob = c(0.75, 
    0.25, 0.95, 0.05, 0.2, 0.25, 0.55, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33)), .Names = c("key", 
"code", "prob"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: Do you mean that for each value of key you want to randomly select a value of code such that the probability of selecting a particular value of code is equal to its probability?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  For example if the `key` value in `df1` is `A` then it should have a 75% chance of being assigned a `code` value of `1` and a 25% chance of being assigned a `code` value of `2`.

Comment: Try `unsplit(Map(function(x,y) transform(x, code=sample(y$code, nrow(x), prob=y$prob, replace=TRUE)), split(df1, df1$key), split(df2, df2$key)), df1$key)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply`, for each row in `df1`, sample from the available codes in `df2`, weighted by `prob`, for the current value of `key`:

```
df1$code = apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
  sample(df2$code[df2$key==x["key"]], 1, prob=df2$prob[df2$key==x["key"]])
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you just want:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  sample_n(1, weight = prob) %>%
  right_join(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
df1$id <- seq(nrow(df1))
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "key", all.x = TRUE)
df3 %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(1, weight = prob)
```

I generated id variable for df1, and merged df1 with all possible code in df2.  Then, `dplyr::sample_n` provides a weighted sampling for each id.
Typical outcome will be

```
Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: id

  key id code prob
1   A  1    1 0.75
2   B  2    1 0.95
3   C  3    3 0.55
4   C  4    3 0.55
5   A  5    1 0.75
6   A  6    1 0.75
7   D  7    1 0.33
```